# Install libspatialindex on Google Cloud AI platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, r-tree, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, libspatialindex

I am trying to import rtree in python

When importing I get this error

```
OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file
```

Researching online it says I need to install libspatialindex when runnning !pip install libspatialindex in Jupyter, I get this error

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libspatialindex (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libspatialindex
```

Researching here https://libspatialindex.org/ it says to install conda and run this

```
conda install -c conda-forge libspatialindex=1.9.3
```

conda is not currently on AI platform notebooks. I'm not sure how to install it, I have not seen instructions online for installing on AI platform

What is the best next step? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions in this link, pasted them into the termal within jupyterlab and it worked
paste the first two blocks of code into terminal. Then you will be ale to import rtree
https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/wiki/1.-Getting-Started